# Problems with the foreach output format

Tags: php, notepad++

I am having a problem with the `foreach` `php` output. The last code I wrote is :

```
foreach (xxx as xx) {
    $output1 = var_export($url, true);
    $output2 = var_export($sername, true);
    $output3 = var_export($alt, true);
    $output4 = var_export($img, true);
    $file = $output1.";".$output2.";".$output3.";".$output4;
    file_put_contents('results.txt', $file, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
}
```

The output from the code above are shown like this:

```
http://www.example1.com;username1;alt1;http://image1.com
http://www.example2.com;username2;alt2;http://image2.com
http://www.example3.com;username3;alt3;http://image3.com
http://www.example4.com;username4;alt4;http://image4.com
http://www.example5.com;username5;alt5;http://image5.com
```

how I can get the result like :

```
http://www.example.com,http://www.example.com,http://www.example.com,http://www.example.com,http://www.example.com ;username1,username2,username3,username4,username5;alt1,alt2,alt3,alt4,alt5;http://image1.com,http://image2.com;http://image3.com,http://image4.com,http://image5.com<br>
```

I also tried it with `notepad ++` for editing results.txt but my knowledge is less.

I appreciate for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<?php
$urls = $usernames = $alts = $imgs = array();
foreach (xxx as xx) {
    ...
    ...
    $urls[] = $url;
    $usernames[] = $username;
    $alts[] = $alt;
    $imgs[] = $img;
}
$file = implode(',', $urls) . ';' . implode(',', $usernames) . ';' . implode(',', $alts) . ';'. implode(',', $imgs);
file_put_contents('results.txt', $file, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$output1=$output2=$output3=$output4='';
foreach (xxx as xx) {
    $output1 .= var_export($url, true);
    $output2 .= var_export($sername, true);
    $output3 .= var_export($alt, true);
    $output4 .= var_export($img, true);
}
$file = $output1.";".$output2.";".$output3.";".$output4;
file_put_contents('results.txt', $file, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
```

Comment: What is the value of xxx and xx?, how do you obtain variables like $url?